# How do I take the nth element of a list and compare to the last nth elements of the same list

Tags: python, counting

Here's what I want to do.

I have a list with 10 numbers(the order matters):

```
ten_numbers = [4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032]
```

I want to take the 10th number, in this case 4032, and I want to compare it against the last 9 numbers and measure if it falls within a +100(4132) -100(3932) range of the 10th number.

In this instance, if the last 9 numbers fall between 3932 and 4132, I want to count this as a success.

Success is if it falls within the range, failure is if it falls outside of it.

I want to count how many times it falls within 3932-4132.

Comment: What is the result you want? An array of booleans?

Comment: The 10th number is 4032, I want to see if there is a number in range of +100 (4132) or -100 (3932) and eventually count successes of any previous 9 numbers fall into that range.

Comment: You should edit the question and add what precisely you want the result to be. Is that a count of values? A boolean? It's not really clear.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks. You're right. I need to take my time asking questions. I just updated it.

Comment: Okay, that's clearer. If you have an array of bools, you can just pass it to `sum()` to get the count of `True` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be enough to answer this. You should notice that ten_numbers is a list.

```
ten_numbers = [4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032]
Answer= [abs(ten_numbers[-1]-ten_numbers[i])<100  for i in range(len(ten_numbers)-1)]
print(sum(Answer))
```

sum(Answer) will count them.

Comment: Watch out, all return True.

Comment: Yes. The main reason is that all the numbers deviate +100. If you change a number in the list, you will see that there is no problem in the code. Try changing ten_numbers[1] to 4000

Comment: The 10th number is 4032, I want to see if there is a number in range of +100 (4132) or -100 (3932) and eventually count successes of any previous 9 numbers fall into that range. Any numbers that fall out of that range don't count.

Comment: 4504-4032 is over 100 :)

Comment: Well. You can change ">" to "<" in my code example and if you want to count them, use sum(Answer).

Comment: This helped answer the code issue for me. If you have a moment, can you translate the python code into simple english for me? The Answer variable specifically.

Comment: len(ten_numbers) will give the amount of elements in the list.  abs(ten_numbers[-1]-ten_numbers[i])<100 will be condition to the boolean list we want to create.  range() is used to provide the number of loops. The for loop inside the list is comparing the elements using the conditions previously described. I used "-1" to avoid comparing the last element with itself.  I hope this explanation could help you.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. If I had a list of say 10,000 items and now I wanted to do this function to every 10th item on the list, how do I go about that? Can you help me with this? So on every 10th item, I check the last prior 9 items from the 10th item and see if it falls within +100/-100 of the 10th item.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple list comprehension (I changed the second value just to make one false):

```
ten_numbers = [4504, 4025, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032]

[abs(el - ten_numbers[-1]) > 100 for el in ten_numbers[:-1]] 
# [True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Given an array of booleans, you can just pass it to `sum()` to get a count:

```
answer = [abs(el - ten_numbers[-1]) > 100 for el in ten_numbers[:-1]]
sum(answer) 
# 8
```

You could also pull the test out into its own function. This might be a little more readable and flexible:

```
ten_numbers = [4504, 4025, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032]

is_different = lambda x: abs(x - ten_numbers[-1]) > 100

list(map(is_different, ten_numbers[:-1]))
# same result
```

Comment: The 10th number is 4032, I want to see if there is a number in range of +100 (4132) or -100 (3932) and eventually count successes of any previous 9 numbers fall into that range. Any numbers that fall out of that range don't count.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your last 9 numbers are: 1-9 or 2-10. If 2-10, then:

```
ten_numbers = [4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032]

max_dev = 100

last = ten_numbers[-1]

results = []
for i in ten_numbers[-9:]:

    results.append(abs(i - last)  < max_dev )

print (results)
```

Comment: Why the math import?

Comment: This all returned TRUE, except for the last number. I want to measure if the last 9 numbers fall within +100 -100 of the 10th number, in this case, between 3932-4132.

Answer (score 0):

This will print out all the difference against your last number.

```
ten_numbers = [4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032]
last_number=ten_numbers[-1]
print(last_number) #check to see if it is the last number i.e 4032


for num in range(0,len(ten_numbers)):
    diff=ten_numbers[num]-last_number
    print(diff)
```